# Identify this Dracaena

Tags: identification, houseplants, dracaena

[image]

How should I care for this one?

[image]

Comment: might be Dracaena sanderiana, but need pic showing the plant from the front, or top to bottom, rather than just the leaf cluster on top

Comment: Hmm, I'm puzzled - the one with white edges to the leaves looks like Dracaena sanderiana or a young D. deremensis 'white stripe' - but I'm not certain about the other one, on the right, with yellow edged leaves. I expected to find they were in different pots... If its D. sanderiana, they need high humidity - best Dracaena for your poor light position would actually be Dracaena marginata though.

Comment: they are in the same pot as you can see. The right one looks fresh to me. :D The left one with faded colors. I thought they are same.

Comment: You might be right, just that one shoot has had more light than the other so the colours are different.  I'm sticking with D. sanderiana - needs high humidity and reasonable light. I bet Kevinsky will know for sure what it is though...which is why I'm not adding this as an answer, because I don't know for sure.

Comment: @Bamboo Is this Dracaena Reflexa(Song of India)? Looks very similar to that one.

Comment: yea, I did look at that one before, and yes, it could be D. reflexa, put it as an answer if you want - I'm not going to because I'm in mourning at the UK EU result, intend to drown my sorrows tonight...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After googling a lot, I now know what plant this is. This is Dracaena Reflexa or Song Of India . Link to know about care:

http://www.houseplant411.com/houseplant/dracaena-reflexa-plant-care-tips